# In Ruby, what is the most correct way to use Regular Expression to match a single digit and **nothing else**?

Tags: ruby, regex

(**Update:** this question's main focus is to test the "nothing else" part)

Given a string s, which can contain anything, what is the most correct regexp in Ruby to check whether it is a single digit and nothing else? (a single digit and only a single digit).

Comment: Wow, Jamie Zawinski (`Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`) strikes again. I lack the Ruby-fu to answer this, but would an equivalent to the Python `len(s) == 1 and s in string.digits` be *that* hard?

Comment: @delnan  what about if you need to check if the string is in the form of `2010-10-08` this way?

Comment: Then it's not a single digit ;) Indeed, this is the kind  of task where regexes shine (and where I happily use them myself - my naive attempt would be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` btw). But for this particular question, I consider a regex overkill.

Comment: @delnan actually, this question is not to test for a single digit as the main purpose.  It is really to ask for the regex way in Ruby to test for "the item and the item ONLY"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/\A\d\z/`

```
irb(main):001:0> "asd\n7\n" =~ /\A\d\Z/
=> nil # works as false
irb(main):002:0> "asd\n7\n" =~ /\A\d\z/
=> nil # works as false
irb(main):083:0> "7\n"=~/\A\d\Z/
=> 0 # \Z fails, need \z
irb(main):084:0> "7\n"=~/\A\d\z/
=> nil # works as false
irb(main):005:0> "7" =~ /\A\d\Z/
=> 0 # works as true
irb(main):006:0> "7" =~ /\A\d\z/
=> 0 # works as true
```

http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html :

```
\z            end of a string
\Z            end of a string, or before newline at the end
```

Comment: it is a strange situation... you have the best solution so far, yet your vote is zero.  I voted 1 for you but someone downvoted your answer.

Comment: +1 for link and correct solution. (If I could give +2, each would merit a +1 on its own. :-))

Answer (score 1):

```
s.scan(/\b\d\b/)

irb(main):001:0> "7\n" =~ /\b\d\z/
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> "7" =~ /\b\d\z/
=> 0
```

Comment: I think this also gets `7\n`, which the OP pointed out in another comment as unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/\A\d(?![\S\W])/`?

```
irb(main):016:0> "7" =~ /\A\d(?![\S\W])/
=> 0
irb(main):017:0> "7\n" =~ /\A\d(?![\S\W])/
=> nil
irb(main):018:0> "aljda\n7\n" =~ /\A\d(?![\S\W])/
=> nil
irb(main):022:0> "85" =~ /\A\d(?![\S\W])/
=> nil
irb(main):023:0> "b5" =~ /\A\d(?![\S\W])/
=> nil
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^\d$
```

`^` is start of the string, `\d` is a digit and `$` is the end of the string

**NOTE**: as stated in comments `^` and `$` work for both lines and strings so if you plan to have a multi-line input you should use `\A` and `\Z`

Comment: `^$` is for line, not string. `"asd\n7\n" =~ /^\d$/` => 4

Comment: He asked about a regexp, not about how to match it.. it is supposed that he knows how to enclose a regex inside `/../` and match with `=~` or `.match` :)